# Change Player's Health

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I don't know how to change the Player's Health in Roblox.

I tried this:

```lua
local Object = game.Workspace.Baseplate
Object.Touched:Connect(function()
     game.StarterPlayer.HealthDisplayDistance = 50
end)
local Killbrick = game.Workspace.Part
```

I thought the 3rd Line changed the health of the Player but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the [Health](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Humanoid#Health) property isn't on a [Player](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player), but rather their [Character](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Player#Character) model's [Humanoid](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Humanoid).

```lua
-- set health to 50 when touching the baseplate
local bp = game.Workspace.Baseplate
bp.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
    -- double check that the other part is a character model
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherPart.Parent) 
    if player then
        -- set the player's health
        player.Character.Humanoid.Health = 50
    end
end)

-- make a kill brick
local Killbrick = game.Workspace.Part
Killbrick.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart.Parent)
    -- double check that the other part is a character model
    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherPart) 
    if player then
        -- kill the player
        player.Character.Humanoid.Health = 0
    end
end)
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I was just asking for a Killbrick but thanks for the Help. Very Much Appreciated.

Comment: Oops, had a small mistake that I needed to fix